# Get Excel range using JavaScript API for Office

Tags: javascript, excel, office365

I am building an App for Office (for desktop Excel) and I am looking for a function in JavaScript API Office version 1.1 that will return the addresses of the column(s) and the row(s) of a user selection. A result like "A1:C3".

I tried with `Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync()` but it only gets me the values. I need to know their address so I can display it in my app. My code is like this:

```
Office.context.document.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Matrix, function (asyncResult) {
    console.log(asyncResult.value);
});
```

The `asyncResult` only gets me an array values. I cannot find any useful help on MSDN or Google. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very late but I hope this alternative can be useful to people working with Excel 2016. You can use the getSelectedRange function on the [workbook](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/workbook) to get the currently selected range and then load the address property like below.

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var selectedRange = ctx.workbook.getSelectedRange();

    selectedRange.load('address');

    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        //selectedRange.address is now available to use
    }).catch(function (error) {
        //handle
    });
}).catch(function (error) {
    //handle
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the a complete working example function:  Just add a test button to this function.  You also need a Div to write your results using the writeToPage function (or amend to your own output area.)

```
function get_rangecoords() {
    Office.context.document.bindings.addFromPromptAsync(Office.BindingType.Matrix,
            { id: "MyMatrixBinding" },
            function (asyncResult) {

                //NOW DO OUTPUT OR ERROR
                if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
                    writeToPage("Error get_rangecoords. " + asyncResult.error.message, 3);
                }
                else {
                    writeToPage("Added new binding with type: " + asyncResult.value.type + " and id: " + asyncResult.value.id, 1);
                }
            });
    Office.select("bindings#MyMatrixBinding", onBindingNotFound).
                addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingSelectionChanged,
              onBindingSelectionChanged,
              function (AsyncResult) {
                  writeToPage("Event handler was added successfully! Change the matrix current selection to trigger the event", 1);
              });

    //Trigger on selection change, get partial data from the matrix 
    function onBindingSelectionChanged(eventArgs) {
        eventArgs.binding.getDataAsync({
            CoercionType: "matrix",
            startRow: eventArgs.startRow,
            startColumn: eventArgs.startColumn,
            rowCount: 1, columnCount: 1
        },


    function (asyncResult) { 
            //NOW DO OUTPUT OR ERROR
            if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
                writeToPage("Error asyncResult: " + asyncResult.error.message, 3);
            }
            else {
                writeToPage('Start Row:' + eventArgs.startRow + ' Start Col:' + eventArgs.startColumn + '\nSelected Row count:' + eventArgs.rowCount + ', Col Count:' + eventArgs.columnCount + '\nFirst Cell Value:' + asyncResult.value[0].toString(), 1);
            }
        });
    }

    //Show error message in case the binding object wasn"t found 
    function onBindingNotFound() {
        writeToPage("The binding object was not found. Please return to previous step to create the binding", 3);
    }
}


function writeToPage(text, varimportance) {

    if (varimportance == "") {
        document.getElementById('Notificationarea').style.color = "black";
    }
    if (varimportance == 1) {
        document.getElementById('Notificationarea').style.color = "darkgreen";
    }
    if (varimportance == 2) {
        document.getElementById('Notificationarea').style.color = "darkorange";
    }
    if (varimportance == 3) {
        document.getElementById('Notificationarea').style.color = "red";
    }

    document.getElementById('Notificationarea').innerText = text;
}
```

For more information, see http://microsoft-office-add-ins.com

Comment: Thank you for your code, stu! I figured out this so far but the challenge is now the sheet, which is selected. I cannot see a way to know how many sheets there are in the file and which one is the range in.

Comment: Hi Miro.  I see what you mean.  You could try something like this:  Lets say you have two sheets.  You create one binding to the relevant range in one sheet and a different binding in sheet 2.   Then you add an event handler to each binding and you will then know which sheet is being triggered.

Comment: function addEvent() { 
        Office.select("bindings#myBindingXXX").addHandlerAsync("bindingDataChanged", myHandler1, function (asyncResult) {
            
            //NOW DO OUTPUT OR ERROR
            if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
                writeToPage('Error E1a myHandler1 addEvent: ' + asyncResult.error.message, 3);
            } else {
                writeToPage('Event handler: myHandler1 added', 1);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: function myHandler1(eventArgs) {//E1b
        eventArgs.binding.getDataAsync({ coerciontype: "matrix" }, function (asyncResult) {
                
            
            //NOW DO OUTPUT OR ERROR
            if (asyncResult.status === "failed") {
                writeToPage('Error E1b myHandler1: Event tracker ' + asyncResult.error.message, 3);
            } else {
                writeToPage('Event tracker, bound data: ' + asyncResult.value, 1);
            }
        });
    }

Comment: The first function above will add the event to myBindingXXX and the second one will output the result if anything is changed in the binding.

Comment: And how do I recognize the number of sheets initially? Java API for Office does not have anything for that, does it?

Comment: You could try looping through cell a1 for all sheet names until you get an error. Might work if the names are still default names.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to create a named item to the whole sheet first and then attach a **SelectionChanged** handler to it. In its arguments you will get the column, row, height, and width of the selection inside that named item.
There is an example by the Microsoft Dev team here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Apps-for-Office-Get-51cc1aac

Comment: i dont see this answer gives the result what actual question is asking.

Comment: @shyam: I'm new to this but it looks like line 47 at https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Add-in-JavaScript-GetSelectionChangeCoordinates/blob/master/DisplayExcelSelectionCoordinatesWeb/App/Home/Home.js  it shows .startRow  and .startColumn as properties of bArgs